# ¿obtener el valor de una consulta count SQL en un resultset de andorid studio

Tags: android, sql-server

espero puedan ayudarme, estoy realizando una aplicación android que se conecte a sql server.
tengo una clase que solo me sirve para contar los valores de una columna

```
public void consulta( ){
ResultSet rs;
PreparedStatement ps=conexion().prepareStatement("select count(*) from 
Articulo");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
}
```

la consulta debe dar 35,el problema es que a la hora de tratar de obtener el resulta, no se si este bien

```
 String dat=rs.getString("articulo");
```

me arroja columna invalida

Comment: Cual es el error que estás consiguiendo? Me parece que debes llamar al método .getResultSet()

Comment: no lo puede convertir en secuencia, donde podria llamar a getResultset();?

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el error que tienes.

Comment: @YeltssinMendoza "Select count(*)" obtiene un valor entero, debes modificar el query, agregue una respuesta.

Comment: ¿Tú quieres contar las filas que hay o quieres el valor de la columna `Articulo`?  Dado que no hay ningún `WHERE` en la consulta, definir eso es fundamental para darte una respuesta adecuada. Si quieres el total, puedes agregar un alias al resultado en la instrucción SQL: `select count(*) total from Articulo` y para obtener el dato:  `int totalFilas=rs.getInt("total");` Y... otra cosa, ¿por qué usas `PreparedStatement` aquí, si esta consulta no necesita ser preparada... ¿Es una consulta para re-usarla? Creo que deberías usar un `Statement` simplemente...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usas `Select count(*)` en tu query, el resultado es un entero,

> [count()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms175997(v=sql.120).aspx) : Devuelve el número de elementos de un grupo.

en este caso no puedes obtener un campo por el nombre:

```
rs.getString("articulo");
```

Para obtener el campo articulo debes cambiar el query a:

```
PreparedStatement ps=conexion().prepareStatement("select * from Articulo");
```

de esta forma podrás obtener verdaderamente los campos de la tabla `Articulo`.

Comment: lo utilice y me funciono correctamente, te agradezco

Comment: Me da gusto que funciono, saludos @YeltssinMendoza!